# How to view variables in parent scope while using VS Code Python Debug Console

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I set a breakpoint in a function that is imported by another script, I would like to be able to view the variables that are in the parent scope from within the VS Code Python Debug Console. Is this possible, perhaps by modifying `launch.json`?

Reproducible example:

I have two files, `scratch_script.py` and `scratch_function.py`. They exist in the same directory.

I place breakpoints where indicated by comments below.

Contents of `scratch_script.py`:

```
import scratch_function

parent_scope_var = 'I disappear'

scratch_function.scratch_function() # breakpoint on this line

pass # breakpoint on this line
```

Contents of `scratch_function.py`:

```
def scratch_function():
    child_scope_var = 'I appear'
    pass # breakpoint on this line
```

I run VS Code Python Debugger from `scratch_script.py`.

At the first break point, I can view `parent_scope_var` in the Python Debug Console, but not `child_scope_var`. So far so good.

When I proceed to the second break point, I can view `child_scope_var`, which is great. But now I cannot view `parent_scope_var`:

```
NameError: name 'parent_scope_var' is not defined
```

On the third breakpoint, the `parent_scope_var` is seen again in the Python Debug Console, but not the `child_scope_var`... Which is as I would expect.

So, my only confusion is, why can't I view `parent_scope_var` when pausing at breakpoints in the called function? The variable still exists, right? Just in the parent scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because when you debug to the second breakpoint, python executes the calling function. At this point, python will open the `scratch_function.py` file.

*First breakpoint:*

[image]

*Second breakpoint:*

[image]

it will only display the variables that exist in the current file, and there is no `parent_scope_var` variable in the `scratch_function.py` file, the python interpreter cannot find `parent_scope_var`, so the watch panel prompts an error: `NameError: name 'parent_scope_var ' is not defined`.

[image]

But as you might guess, the variable still exists at this point, just inside the `scratch_script.py` file. At this point, you can open the `scratch_script.py` file, hover the mouse over the `parent_scope_var` variable, and vscode will clearly show you the variable value at this time.

[image]

On a side note, you can also see the previous `parent_scope_var` variable in the **CALL STACK** panel.

[image]

*PS:* a setting to display variable values inline in code files when debugging:

```json
//file:settings.json
{
    "debug.inlineValues": "on",  
}
```